# How can I make all three containers draggable in Dragula, if all three are rendered using a method? Using React js and Dragula (not react-dragula)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dragula

React beginner here. So basically, I want to have 3 columns with elements that can be dragged to reorder inside the same column or move to a different column. The code for it is separated into 2 classes to separate what relevant element should be in each column.

Here is the code for the class (Swimlane.js) that defines the structure of each column:

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import Dragula from 'dragula';
import './Swimlane.css';



export default class Swimlane extends React.Component {

  render() {

  const dragulaDecorator = (componentBackingInstance) => { 
      if (componentBackingInstance) {
        let options = {
          moves: function (el, source, handle, sibling) {
            return true;
          },
          accepts: function (el, target, source, sibling) {
            return true;
          },
          direction: 'vertical',
          copy: false,           
          copySortSource: false,
          revertOnSpill: false,              
          removeOnSpill: false,   
          mirrorContainer: document.body,   
          ignoreInputTextSelection: true,
        }

        console.log('componentBackingInstance: ');
        console.log(componentBackingInstance);
        Dragula([componentBackingInstance]);
      }
    };

    const cards = this.props.clients.map(client => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={client.id}
          id={client.id}
          name={client.name}
          description={client.description}
          status={client.status}
        />
      );
    })
    return (
      <div className="Swimlane-column" class="Swimlane Column">
        <div className="Swimlane-title">{this.props.name}</div>
        <div className="Swimlane-dragColumn" ref={dragulaDecorator}> {/* this is the column that contains all my elements, and the one I want to make my container */}
          {cards}
        </div>
      </div>);
  }

}
```

Swimlane.js is called in this next class, Board.js to actually render all the components.

```
import React from 'react';
import Dragula from 'dragula';
import 'dragula/dist/dragula.css';
import Swimlane from './Swimlane';
import './Board.css';

export default class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const clients = this.getClients();

    this.state = {
      clients: {
        backlog: clients.filter(client => !client.status || client.status === 'backlog'),
        inProgress: clients.filter(client => client.status && client.status === 'in-progress'),
        complete: clients.filter(client => client.status && client.status === 'complete'),
      }
    }
    this.swimlanes = {
      backlog: React.createRef(),
      inProgress: React.createRef(),
      complete: React.createRef(),
    }



  }

  getClients() {
    return [
      // [id, name, description, status]
      ['1','Name 1','Description 1', 'backlog'],
      ['2','Name 2','Description 2', 'in-progress'],
      ['3','Name 3','Description 3', 'backlog'],
      ['4','Name 4','Description 4', 'complete'],
    ].map(companyDetails => ({
      id: companyDetails[0],
      name: companyDetails[1],
      description: companyDetails[2],
      status: companyDetails[3],
    }));
  }
  renderSwimlane(name, clients, ref) {
    return (
      <Swimlane name={name} clients={clients} dragulaRef={ref}/>
    );
  }

  render() {

    return ( 
      <div className="Board">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row"> 
            <div className="col-md-4">
              {this.renderSwimlane('Backlog', this.state.clients.backlog, this.swimlanes.backlog)}
              </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
              {this.renderSwimlane('In Progress', this.state.clients.inProgress, this.swimlanes.inProgress)}
              </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
              {this.renderSwimlane('Complete', this.state.clients.complete, this.swimlanes.complete)}
              </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So, the method getClients() is used to make a 'state' prop and a 'swimlanes' prop which are used by the renderSwimlane() method to render 3 columns all with relevant information.

Right now, if I run this code all draggable elements inside the three 'Swimlane-dragColumn' divs can be ordered inside their own containers, but cannot be moved to other containers. Also, please ignore the statement importing Card.js, it is a class that basically shows what each draggable element should look like (colour etc.).

A similar question was asked here         ([how to move a dragula draggable element to another div in react-dragula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051349/how-to-move-a-dragula-draggable-element-to-another-div-in-react-dragula?rq=1))        but I cant understand what the answer means (and I can't comment because of Lack of Reputation). How do I get all three columns which have the classname 'Swimlane-dragColumn' that would be rendered to be considered as viable containers? I have been able to find out that I am supposed to use the 'push' function somewhere but I don't know how I to implement that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
  componentDidMount(){
    Dragula(Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('Swimlane-dragColumn')))
    }
  componentDidUpdate(){
    Dragula(Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('Swimlane-dragColumn')))
    }
```

I believe this is from inside sherpa and the task is related to react hooks try this and work ahead

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to adding a library, I wrote this one here: https://github.com/jpribyl/react-hook-dragula

It provides strong typing and allows you to use `dragula` in a `react` environment pretty painlessly. It only adds 22kb to your bundle (assuming you already have react + dragula)

It sounds to me like you just need multiple containers to achieve your desired result. The first example on this demo should be similar: https://johnpribyl.com/react-hook-dragula/

Code available here: https://github.com/jpribyl/react-hook-dragula/blob/main/example/src/examples/TwoContainerExample.tsx

Let me know if anything is unclear! I believe your solution would be something like this:

```
<Dragula className="row">
  <DragulaContainer className="col">
    <Draggable>
      column 1
    </Draggable>
  </DragulaContainer>

  <DragulaContainer className="col">
    <Draggable>
      column 2
    </Draggable>
  </DragulaContainer>

  <DragulaContainer className="col">
    <Draggable>
      column 3
    </Draggable>
  </DragulaContainer>
</Dragula>
```